# How to choose negative examples to build a training set?

Tags: supervised-learning

I want to use supervised machine learning method to do binary classfication, so a training set is needed. I already have the positive examples.

My question is that all my negative examples are randomly selected from a very large dataset which may contain only a few positive examples.

Is this approach right to construct the training set? Is any approach to evaluate the training set, especially negative examples?

Answer (score 2):

There is a good [literature survey on active learning](http://burrsettles.com/pub/settles.activelearning.pdf) by Burr Settles, this would be a good place to start in selecting negative examples that have the largest effect on the model.

Comment: Thanks Dikran, actually, can active learning find a most appropriate subset of negative examples to stand for all types of negative examples?

Comment: I would have thought so, active learning tries to successively identify patterns that produce the greatest improvement in the model.  If all of the unused patterns in the pool are negative patterns, hopefully it will select the most informative ones first.  However, as for most statistical algorithms, your mileage may vary (as they say http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary )